# How to calculate basic.stats of each population using hierfstat in R

Tags: r, fst

I would like to calculate some summary statistics such as FIS, FST, Ho, He for "each population" using a `hierfstat` object with 217 samples and 38,000 sites. Although the `basic.stats()` function estimated FIS, Ho, Hs for each population, FST and other statistics are not estimated for each population but only with the overall values. Is it possible to calculate the population-specific FST for each population using `hierfstat` in R?
Thanks for any responses and suggestions!
I tried separating samples based on population first and calculated FST and FIS for each population, but I am not sure if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer, here's what worked for me:
After creating a geno_object with the df2genind function, do the following;

```
gen_sub = popsub(geno_object)

fst = genet.dist(gen_sub, method = "WC84")
```

This will give you a pairwise Fst.

Check [this link](https://tomjenkins.netlify.app/tutorials/r-popgen-getting-started/) for more details.